# iOS Linker Error using prime31 StoreKit Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, unity-game-engine, prime31

I am using a Prime31 plugin for storekit integration in my Unity3d Project.I am building it for the iOS platform .But as soon as i compile my code, Xcode is giving me linker Error which is attached with a screenshot below and i am unable to find the solution for this.

I have added Storekit.framework in my build settings .If any one please suggest me that what kind of error is this and how it can be solved?

Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Comment: You tagged this with ios5. There are some restrictions before iOS 6 like hosted content. Did you try out iOS 6 as build target?

Comment: Hey Kay nothing happend

Comment: I have the same problem. DO u have any solution.